# Algolia Instant Search can't add numeric filter / not working

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js

I try to have an always on filter in my Instantsearch App (before & while the user is searching) & tried both ways from the docs:

1st

```
var search = instantsearch({
    appId: '------------------,
    apiKey: '-----------------',
    indexName: 'words',
    urlSync: true,
    filters: 'sendDateUnix<'+ Date.now(),
});
```

2nd

```
var search = instantsearch({
    appId: '------------------,
    apiKey: '-----------------',
    indexName: 'words',
    urlSync: true,
    numericFilters: [
        'sendDateUnix<'+ Date.now()
    ]
});
```

As you can see, I have an property that is a Unix timestamp and would like to only get results where this timestamp ist greater then now. It works perfectly when I set this param in the algolia interface. It also does not work when i write the fully filter: 'sendDateUnix < 1519751110'

IS Version:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/instantsearch.js/1/instantsearch.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `numericFilters` option doesn't exist on `instantsearch`. You need to wrap the additional parameters in the `searchParameters` attribute. See [the documentation](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v1/documentation/#initialization) for more informations.

```
const search = instantsearch({
  appId: '------------------,
  apiKey: '-----------------',
  indexName: 'words',
  urlSync: true,
  searchParameters: {
    numericFilters: ['sendDateUnix < ' + Date.now()],
  },
});
```